# Why does the ExtJS style not match the official web demo?

Tags: javascript, extjs

[This is the official demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s5tg.png)

[This is my demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG1b0.png)

The ***splitter element*** style is different, I don't know why this happened.

And my code is here, and I put my demo to https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3jb8

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just the splitter. Try this and find out your personal value instead of 30.

```
        defaults: {
            collapsible: true,
            split: {width: 30, height: 30},
            bodyPadding: 10
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the code!

Indeed, this is a nice question: initially I thought the problem was that you were playing with different version of the framework (Kitchen Sink from the screenshot is version **7.0.0** meanwhile you are using ExtJs **7.5.1** in the Fiddle).

But using the same framework version didn't solve the problem of the truncated splitters'size.

A workaround tested in your fiddle could be to set manually the height (for the *horizontal* splitters) and the width (for the *vertical* ones) while rendering the container panel like this:

```
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(panel){
            Ext.ComponentQuery.query(panel.xtype + " splitter").forEach(splitter => {
                splitter.vertical ? splitter.setWidth(15) : splitter.setHeight(15);
            });
        }
    }
```